# JQuery and CSS file is not working from external file

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to access the jQuery from external file put it is not working on my page. I checked my code and also searched in internet but not finding my mistake...

clearableformfield.jsp

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery.clearable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/jquery.clearable.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="dom">
<input type="text"  class="foo"></input>
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.foo').clearable();
});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**jquery.clearable.js**

```
$(this).css({'border-width': '0px', 'outline': 'none'})
    .wrap('<div id="sq" class="divclearable"></div>')
    .parent()
    .attr('class', $(this).attr('class') + ' divclearable')
    .append('<a class="clearlink" href="javascript:"></a>');

$('.clearlink')
    .attr('title', 'Click to clear this textbox')
    .click(function() {

        $(this).prev().val('').focus();

});
```

**jquery.clearable.css**

```
.divclearable {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    padding-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

a.clearlink {
    background: url("close-button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    z-index: 2000;
    border: 0px solid;
}

#dom{
    background-color:#b0c4de;}
}
```

All these file are inside the web content in the JQuery folder

Comment: Is your html file also in JQerey folder?

Comment: double check your file path

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of the file? because there must be jquery folder at the root of html file and this jquery folder must contain jquery.clearable.js and jquery.clearable.css files

Comment: Your `jquery.clearable.js` file won't work, because: (1) you don't wait for document ready (2) `$(this)` is meanless, you must write a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path should be like this

```
xxx.html
JQuery [folder]
   |
   |---jquery.clearable.js
   |---jquery.clearable.css
   '---close-button.png
```

**Updated**

Your HTML file should be like this

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery.clearable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/jquery.clearable.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <TITLE>Clearable Textboxes in jQuery</TITLE>

</HEAD>
<BODY>


<input type="text" class="clearable style1" size="30"></input>
&nbsp;
<input type="text" class="clearable style1"></input>

</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clearable').clearable()
});
</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

**JQuery/jquery.clearable.js** file should be like this

```
jQuery.fn.clearable = function() {
    
    $(this).css({'border-width': '0px', 'outline': 'none'})
        .wrap('<div id="sq" class="divclearable"></div>')
        .parent()
        .attr('class', $(this).attr('class') + ' divclearable')
        .append('<a class="clearlink" href="javascript:"></a>');

    $('.clearlink')
        .attr('title', 'Click to clear this textbox')
        .click(function() {
            
            $(this).prev().val('').focus();

    });
}
```

**JQuery/jquery.clearable.css** file should be like this

```
.divclearable {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;    
    padding-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

a.clearlink {
    background: url("close-button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;    
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    z-index: 2000;
    border: 0px solid;
}
```

and add [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yneTc.png) to JQuery folder.

Comment: what's your mail id.? I will send you that verified file.

Comment: i checked your code jquerey is working but using it i want to make clearable form is field that is still not working.  i am usng this xample http://viralpatel.net/blogs/clearable-textbox-jquery/

Comment: I updated code for you. Copy the code from here and past it to your corresponding files. Then add the image in "JQerey" folder.

Comment: have you checked this code in your system because it is not working here and thanks for being so helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a DOCTYPE like so at the very top of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This can cause problems in older versions of Internet Explorer, and may be causing your problems.

Without any more information it's very difficult to tell what could be the problem, what browser are you using? What errors are thrown in the console (firebug/IE Developer tools/Chrome dev tools) is it a 404 error or a different JavaScript error?

What does your directory structure look like? Are you sure things are in the right place and you haven't misnamed things? I notice you've put the folder name as `JQerey` is this an intentional spelling or a mistake?

It could also be that the file is returning with the wrong Mime Type, although I doubt this is the case.

Comment: <! DOCTYPE> Is not a problem when i am using jquery in same page it is working but from the outsidefile it is not working